# AutoResetEvent blocks the BackgroundWorker progress report

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar, backgroundworker, autoresetevent

I am using BackgroundWorker in my application. I am able to display the progress bar change when the Backgroundworker is still busy. However when I use AutoResetEvent to wait until Backgroundworker is complete, I dont see the progress bar changes. Is there an alternative way, that I can wait for the BackgroundWorker to complete and to dislpay the progressbar changes? I am pretty new to C# framework and programming.

```
private AutoResetEvent _resetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

private void InitializeBackgroundWorker()
        {
            parserBackgroundWorker.DoWork +=
                new DoWorkEventHandler(parserBackgroundWorker_DoWork);
            parserBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted +=
                new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
            parserBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
            parserBackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged +=
                new ProgressChangedEventHandler(
            parserBackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged);
            parserBackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            parserBackgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        }

 private void parserBackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender,
            DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the BackgroundWorker that raised this event.
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            parser.Parse((SegmentFile)e.Argument);
            _resetEvent.Set();
        }

        // This event handler deals with the results of the 
        // background operation. 
        private void parserBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(
            object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // First, handle the case where an exception was thrown. 
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
            }
            else if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                // Next, handle the case where the user canceled  
                // the operation. 
                // Note that due to a race condition in  
                // the DoWork event handler, the Cancelled 
                // flag may not have been set, even though 
                // CancelAsync was called.
                //resultLabel.Text = "Canceled";
            }
            else
            {
                // Finally, handle the case where the operation  
                // succeeded.
                //resultLabel.Text = e.Result.ToString();
            }           
        }

        // This event handler updates the progress bar. 
        private void parserBackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender,
            ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

parserBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(selectedSegFile);
// when I comment this code I do see the progress bar change as the thread is doing the work.
_resetEvent.WaitOne();
```

Comment: Why do you want to block UI thread? You should place code that was after _resetEvent.WaitOne(); in RunWorkerCompleted()

Comment: As Dmitry explained, you are blocking the UI thread when invoking `WaitOne`. Your `BackgroundWorker` is updating the `Value` property of the progress bar and invalidating it, but the thread which is supposed to do the actual painting of the control is blocked waiting for the event.

Comment: I use this backgroundworker in multiple places so I cannot place the code in RunWorkerCompleted().

Comment: @savi: I don't really understand how your program is organized, but you can easily attach and detach different `RunWorkerCompleted` event handlers from wherever you wish. Or, you can have a single handler which will behave differently for different cases. The thing that you certainly don't want to do is block the UI thread (because in that case you don't need the background worker at all).

Comment: Can you show an example for "but you can easily attach and detach different RunWorkerCompleted event handlers from wherever you wish. Or, you can have a single handler which will behave differently for different cases."?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you had this code:

```
parserBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(selectedSegFile);
_resetEvent.WaitOne();
MessageBox.Show("Work Done");
```

then you can place the code after `_resetEvent.WaitOne();` in method and attach this method to `RunWorkerCompleted` event and remove `_resetEvent.WaitOne();`

```
private void MyRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Work Done");
}

private void InitializeBackgroundWorker()
{
    //old init code
    // you can attach as many methods to RunWorkerCompleted as you want
    parserBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += parserBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    parserBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += myRunWorkerCompleted;
}
```

Also you can give a `delegate` as a paramter to `BackgroundWorker` and call it in `parserBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted`

```
class ParserWorkerParameters
{
    public String SegFile { get; set; }
    public Action CallBack { get; set; }

    public ParserWorkerParameters(string segFile, Action callBack)
    {
       SegFile = segFile;
       CallBack = callBack;
    }
}

parserBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(new ParserWorkerParameters("someString", () =>  MessageBox.Show("worker complete")));

private void parserBackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    ParserWorkerParameters param = e.Argument as ParserWorkerParameters;
    parser.Parse((SegmentFile)param.SegFile);
    e.Result = param;
}

private void parserBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //old code
    ParserWorkerParameters param = e.Result as ParserWorkerParameters;
    if (param.CallBack != null)
    {
        param.CallBack();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 This is actually the most general approach (passing a callback delegate when starting the worker), I only mentioned it but I see you have provided a full example.

Comment: I think I got what you are trying to say. Let me try this approach and check. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As already discussed in comments above, the problem is that you're blocking the UI thread when invoking the `WaitOne` method. Your `BackgroundWorker` is actually updating the `Value` property of the progress bar (and by doing this, invalidating it), but the thread which is supposed to do the actual painting of the control is blocked waiting for the event.

Based on your comments, it appears like your concern is how to start the worker with different parameters, and handle the `RunWorkerCompleted` event differently based on these parameters.

One approach might be to attach a different handler for that event, whenever you start the worker from a certain point in your program:

```
// attach the handler
parserBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += FirstCaseHandler;

// run it
parserBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(selectedSegFile);
```

In that case, the first thing each of your handlers should do is detach itself:

```
void FirstCaseHandler(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // detach this specific handler
    parserBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted -= FirstCaseHandler;

    // do stuff
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can attach a single handler and use it to handle different cases based on the worker result.

In that case you can set the `Result` property of the `DoWorkEventArgs` to pass the resulting object to the handler when your `DoWork` method is done:

```
void parserBackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender,
        DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     // do stuff
     var parserResult = parser.Parse((SegmentFile)e.Argument);

     // set the Result property with a custom object which 
     // will allow you to know which case you need to handle

     // this can be simply: e.Result = e.Argument;

     // or, you can create an instance of your own class, something like:
     e.Result = new WorkerResult(e.Argument, parserResult);
}
```

In this case, you will check the value of `e.Result` inside the `RunWorkerCompleted` handler:

```
void parserBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(
       object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var resultInfo = e.Result as WorkerResult; // or whatever

    // do the right thing based on its value
}
```

You can even pass a callback delegate as the argument and have this method called from the `RunWorkerCompleted` handler, so you really have numerous options.

Comment: I like your idea about unsubscribing FirstCaseHandler, because it makes your code behavior identical to OP code, but it took me some time to understand that.